# combit List & Label . Problems with connecting objects to layers and to specific pages

Tags: list, label, layer

regarding combit List & Label Version 24, Designer

I want specific objects on specific layers and these on specific pages.

I use page breaks on the objects saying "break before ..." and I want the layers connected to specific pages like this:

```
Layer 1, Page = 1
Layer 2, Page = 2
Layer 3, Page = 3
Layer 4, Page = 4
Layer 5, Page = 5
```

... but I do not get any working result with it.

With these "page = number" expression I do not get any result.

For now I have 3 pages and organized it like this:

```
Layer 1 = Page() = 1
Layer 2 = Page() >= 1
Layer 3 = Page() > 1
```

The result shows 3 pages and the second object (that is connected to layer 2) shows up on page 2 and 3.

Is there any simple solution to make it happen that every object is connected to one layer and that one layer to only one page?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Somehow it now works. After checking the Barcode example demo it works.

The page connections to the layers work fine with

```
Page() = <number>
```

On previous tries it did not …

Anyway, all fine now.